# How php can parse html to find links in user input?

Tags: php, html, parsing, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)
>   [PHP Linkify Links In Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080826/php-linkify-links-in-content)

I want to parse html to find links, but i want not only to find links like http://www.aaa.com, but also links like www.apple.com or just apple.com. I dont wand to find a tags. I want to find links in user input text.

Comment: You want to find `<a>` tags? CSS `@include` directives? `src="..."` attributes? links/hostnames in text nodes?

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php

Comment: I want to find links in user input text.

Comment: @Graydot that's not what he's looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here in [preg_match Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

The expression I would use:

```
/https?:\/?\/?[^\ ]+/i
```