# Replace text with link only when it is not a link already (in php)

Tags: php, regex

I have to replace 'page1' in some code with '`<a href="/page1">page1</a>`'

However, I only want to do so if it is not already a link. How can I do the same using php regular expressions.

- Use case 1 - page1  -> should change to `<a href="/page1">page1</a>`
- Use case 2 - `<a href="/page1">page1</a>` -> nothing should be changed

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Linkify Links In Content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080826/php-linkify-links-in-content)

Comment: isn't it something which should be trivial by a simple reg exp?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact link text in advance then you can just check for the existence of  quotes or angled brackets before and after it. **Are you sure this is the question you should be asking?**

For the exact string 'page1':

```
preg_replace('#(^|[^"\'>])\s*(page1)\s*($|[^"\'<])#is', '<a href="$2">$2</a>', $s);
```

**This is a bad solution** though really. You should use a HTML parser because regex is never reliable for things like this. It *could* break under certain conditions.

Comment: The `s` modifier has no affect on a pattern with no dots in it.