# How to replace the urls into clickable links except anchor text & anchor href?

Tags: php, javascript

```
$str="hi this http://google.com   <a href="http:
//yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>";
```

i want to convert http://google.com to clickable link in above string but i don't want convert already anchor text & anchor href.

how can i achieve that one using php / javascript?

Comment: It's called linkifying. see http://buildinternet.com/2010/05/how-to-automatically-linkify-text-with-php-regular-expressions/

Comment: you should not write **"Regards and kK"**

Comment: can u check once my requirement exactly.. i just modified that one?

Comment: @KalyanKrishna see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291451/1273830

Answer (score 0):

you can use [auto link function](https://github.com/iamcal/lib_autolink) to do this type of things